# What's the relationship between ops/second and percentage slower in JSPerf?

Tags: javascript, jsperf

[image: JSPerf test results]

How is the "X% slower" number computed? I thought maybe it was:

```
(fastest - slower) / fastest
```

but in this case, that's:

```
(672555 - 194412) / 672555 = 0.7109351651537792
```

Maybe the margin of error is used as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js/blob/7fc4c3cf7c4bccff4dbce58883a4181c2e830f85/example/jsperf/ui.js#L556:

```
percent = (1 - (hz / fastestHz)) * 100
```